# Chrome not running D3.js

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, d3.js

I know this is some sort of security issue with chrome not running files it doesnt trust, but would anyone know is there anyway to fix this problem?

Other than running my code on a server.

Thanks.

Comment: `python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8088` in the directory where you store the files? The server is not THAT far away...

Answer (score 3):

I presume that you're running with a local file. When starting Chrome you can use the `--allow-file-access-from-files` flag to make it load local JSON (for example) or `--disable-web-security` to disable the security mechanisms altogether.

Note that depending on your version of Chrome these flags may or may not work.

Comment: How do I use these flags? Do I put them in the header of my doc??

Comment: No, you give them to Chrome when starting it. You'll need to start it from the command line.

Answer (score 0):

Install `http-server` globally:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server

This is a really fast way to develop locally. Disabling the file access with the flag will lead you to other bad practices and unexpected situations.

Answer (score -1):

If using windows, you can create a shortcut where the "Target" includes the commands (instead of having to run Chrome from the command line:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --allow-file-access-from-files
```

Comment: It should be added as a comment below the answer which specify to use the argument.